# OpenGrok: is it possible to copy the File full path?

Tags: opengrok

When OpenGrok has a file search results,

I can't find a way to copy the full path name of the matched file result into clipboard, so I can open the file in Visual Studio or any other editor.

If I browse into a file result there's the xref full path on the top pf th page, but he problem is that it has forward slash instead of backslash.
I can't easily convert this into path that I can use with file->Open dialog

Is there a way to do that easily?

Answer (score 0):

Use a bookmarklet to convert the path. Here is an example:

```
javascript:void(function(){console.log($("#Masthead").find("a[href]:last").attr("href").replace(/\//g,"\\"))}())
```

which copies the path to the JavaScript console.